# Unable to Bind ListView.SelectedItems.Count to Button.IsEnabled

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I have a Button that I want to bind to the listview's selectedItem count. I cannot find where my error is. The button state is always enabled regardless of testListView.SelectedItems.Count.

Do I need a converter of some sort? If the Count is zero, it should implicitly convert that to a false no ?

```
<ListView x:Name="testListView"  SelectionMode="Multiple" BorderThickness="1">            
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>                       
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

<Button x:Name="Button" Content="TestButton" IsEnabled="False" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=testListView, Path=SelectedItems.Count}"/>
```

Comment: What does the error message says?

Comment: @Mephy No error in the output window unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `SelectedItems` collection's `Count` property is of type `int`, and the `IsEnabled` property expects a `bool` input, and no implicit conversion of `int` to `bool` exists in C#, you'll need a converter or a data trigger.

A simple `IValueConverter` should do the trick, just use something like

```
return ((int)value) > 0;
```

as content of the `Convert` function!

Answer (score 1):

Update using a DataTrigger via a Style; something like this should work:

```
<Button x:Name="Button" Content="TestButton">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=testListView, Path=SelectedItems.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```